# Two has_many links between the same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-many

I have **users** which have **products** through a habtm link, which is working.

I want to add a link between the **user** model and the **product** model, to keep track of the **creator** of that product (who doesn't always own the product, of course)

But when I write in my **user** and **product** models a new link, the application screws up because I can't distinguish the **creator** of a **product** from the owner of (a lot of) **products**.

Can you help me ? Here is my models :

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users   # THIS IS OK (with appart table)
  has_many :users, :as => creator  # THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK AT THE MOMENT
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  belongs_to :user                 # THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK AT THE MOMENT
  default_scope :order => "username ASC"
end
```

The database is ok, and I can store the user_id under the creator column from my product, but the link **product.creator.name** doesn't work (because of the model is not correct, I presume), I can only read the user_id which is in the column but not get the user object with all his attributes.

rem : **user.products** works perfectly, but only when I remove my new link for creator...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:as` syntax is for polymorphic associations - this is not what you want.  Your comments about your column names are a bit ambiguous, so I'm going to assume that you have a `user_id` column in your `products` table which is the id of the creator of that product (I'm only including the relevant associations)...

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :creator, :foreign_key => :user_id, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  has_many :owned_products, :class_name => "Product"
end
```

Comment: I checked to quickly the answer, because it is not yet working. I have no access to my key creator anymore, and product.creator returns nil all the time (even when I see the user_id in the column of the table with SQlite viewer)

Comment: and user.owned_products returns no such column: products.user_id

Comment: As I said, I assumed that the column in `products` that pointed to the creator of a product was called `user_id`.  Change `user_id` to whatever that column is called.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice gem for that: https://github.com/spovich/userstamp

I used it in my project and it works good - you just adds 'stampable' to your models and then creator_id (and updater_id) are filled authomaticly.