# in Rails, need to set many-to-many relationship and one-to-many relationships between the same two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an app in which projects belong to one owner (a user) and have and belong to many members (users).

I have the following code set up in the models to handle these associations.  Note, project has owner_id in its database but not member_id

project model code

```
attr_accessible :description, :name, :owner_id, :avatar_url

belongs_to :owner, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: "User"
has_and_belongs_to_many :members, class_name: "User"
```

user model code

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
has_many :owned_projects, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: "owner_id"
has_many :associated_projects, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: "member_id"
```

On a given project, I can call p.owner but not p.members.  And I for a user I can call u.owned_projects or u.projects but not u.associated_projects.

When I try those commands, I get the following errors

```
1.9.3p194 :003 > p.members
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "projects_users" ON "users"."id" = "projects_users"."user_id" WHERE "projects_users"."project_id" = 3
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: projects_users: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "projects_users" ON "users"."id" = "projects_users"."user_id" WHERE "projects_users"."project_id" = 3
```

and

```
1.9.3p194 :007 > ryan.associated_projects
Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."member_id" = 14593
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: projects.member_id: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."member_id" = 14593
```

How can I set up these models so they'll work as I intend?

Note: I modeled my code after - [Two has_many links between the same models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509227/two-has-many-links-between-the-same-models) but it hasn't helped.

Comment: do you have a intermediate table in your database to combine the Member and the Project?

Comment: I don't, should I?  And if so, how?

Comment: you have to store the ids somehow. Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a has_many_and_belongs_to relationship in your User and Project models. Also you need a intermediate table inbetween. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

```
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

     attr_accessible :description, :name, :owner_id, :avatar_url

     belongs_to :owner, foreign_key: :owner_id, class_name: "User"
     has_and_belongs_to_many :members, class_name: "User"

end

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
     has_many :owned_projects, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: "owner_id"

end
```

As said, you will have to have a middle table between member Project and User(member).
You had that error when you tried to see project members: **no such table: projects_users**

```
Projects_Users Table
user_id | project_id
```

Comment: Is this table a new model or can I just write a migration creating the table?

Comment: Just write a migration and run it, no need for a model

Comment: Actually, it loks like the content of the project_users table should be user_id and project_id.  But with that edit, it works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh sorry, a stupid mistake, of course it wont need to reference to both user and member ID's. Glad i could help :)

Comment: Eric, `belongs_to :associated_projects, class_name: "Project", foreign_key: :member_id` isn't really right. It would say that a user belongs to a project. That isn't right is it? ..gah i didn't wanna reject your edit but i accidently skiped it and it got rejected. Anyways, what is not working with this solution?