# Rails - two assciations between the same models with many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, database-migration

My problem is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509227/two-has-many-links-between-the-same-models), but with some problematic differences.

I'd like to make two relationships between `User` and `Service` - one-to-many relationship of ownership and many-to-many relationship of saving.

My Service model:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user #ownership
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :time_slots
  has_many :pictures
  has_and_belongs_to_many :saving_users, class_name: 'User' #saving
end
```

My User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :services #ownership
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :time_slots, through: :reservations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :saved_services, class_name: 'Service' #saving
end
```

Trying to get `@user.saved_services` I receive this error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "services_users" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "services".* FROM "services" INNER JOIN
>   "services_use...

I dropped database and built it again, but this didn't help me.

Unfortunately [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236641/pgundefinedtable-error-relation-does-not-exist) also doesn't work.

Comment: do you really want to name this association like this: `@user.saved_services` and `@service.saving_users` because the convention would be `@user.services` and `@service.users`.. I can explain you based on the convention or based on your requirements

Comment: did you create the HABTM table `services_users`?

Comment: did you create a UserServiceSave model? if so, you will need to change the  `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations to `has_many :through => :user_service_save` associations.

Comment: Hm, okay, it works now, but I'm not sure what I was doing wrong. Maybe I did some mess in git and copied error message from another version. However, thanks.